# Run Selenium Webdriver in separate thread

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am using the Selenium Webdriver (with jBehave) for testing. I have observed that if I run the same simultaneously with other programs , it captures some invalid inputs (may be through keyboard) and the test fails (during some asserts).

So is there any way by which I can make it run independently such that it does not get affected by any other user action running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Use remote webdriver instead of webdriver. Ensure that nobody is doing simultaneously work on the node executing tests.

Comment: Is there some way to do this locally ?

Comment: for firefox driver you can disable native events by setting property webdriver.enable.native.events. Refer http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver#Important_System_Properties